# higher priority: contract or law

Tags: contract-law, landlord

In my country there is a 3 month time length given by law, that applies when either one of tenant or landlord interrupts the contract about renting an appartment, between the announcement and the moving out points of time.

I am renting a place. My landlord wrote into our contract 5 months instead of the 3 months. I have signed the contract.

Which one of these two numbers is valid now? The one given by the law (3 months) or the one in our contract (5 months)?

Comment: where? in some laws it is a minimum, that can be contractually altered, in others it dictates this and no other.

Comment: The correct answer will vary in different jurisdictions: by country, and in federal countries, by state or province. In some cases it may vary by municipality, as much landlord/tenant law is local. However, the policy here is that a question need to state a jurisdiction, and if none is stated, an answer may specify the jurisdiction(s) for which it is valid. Thus this question should not be closed for lacking details.

Answer (score 1):

In Germany the law is 3 months unless you have specifically "verzichten" your right to move out until a certain date or as in your case.

Regardless of what you both agreed in the contract it can still be done away with *if* both the parties agree. E.g. if you find a new tenant and your landlord agrees with it, you can even move out tomorrow.